# Link is not defined error in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react app with the following code:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
var Matches = React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    },
    ...
    componentWillMount: function() {
        var router = this.context.router;
        ...
        router.push('/pay');
    }
});
```

For some reason when I try to go to "/pay", I get the following exception:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Link is not defined"
```

My route is defined as following:

```
var auth_and_info_check = function auth_and_info_check(nextState, replace, callback) {
        if (!_horizon_connect2.default.hasAuthToken() && !nextState.location.pathname.endsWith("login")) {
            replace({ pathname: '/login' });
            callback();
        } else if (_horizon_connect2.default.hasAuthToken() && nextState.location.pathname.endsWith("/")) {
            _horizon_connect2.default.currentUser().fetch().subscribe(function (user) {
                if (!(user.hasOwnProperty('data') && user.data.hasOwnProperty('phone'))) {
                    replace({ pathname: '/user_info' });
                    callback();
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        } else {
            callback(); //In my case after routing "/pay" I call this callback
        }
    };

<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route component={Layout}>
        ...
        <Route path="/pay" component={Pay} onEnter={auth_and_info_check}/>
        ...
    </Router>
</Router>
```

Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide `Pay` component code?

Comment: Looks like your import of Link itself is not working. Are you using it anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like we need to look at your build file. Unless you are double sure that Link is getting included in your final js file, sounds like that's the issue. You may want to add that as additional info to the question.

Comment: I am not using Link anywhere in this component. My Pay component is just a regular component with render method and I bring it for the router with:         import Pay from './pay';

Comment: I stumbled upon this question because { Link } was not working for me, but I was not requesting it either. Once I added imported it like you do, mine worked. I'm on `"react-router": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",` and using un-ejected `"react-scripts": "0.8.4"`.

Answer (score 0):

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

It is working fine